# Is there any kind of “motor current/load limit curve”, like the one for wires?

Tags: induction-motor, circuit-breaker, iec

When we try to select a motor protective circuit breaker (for an IEC induction motor), we can compare its tripping curve to the motor’s time-current curve during starting and steady-state. To avoid nuisance tripping, motor’s curve should be under cb’s tripping curve.

[image: Tripping Characteristics of a Circuit Breaker, Contactor, and Overload Relay Protection System - Scneider Electric - EDCED115066ENUS]

At the same time, to ensure that the cable can withstand the current, its current limit curve as a function of time (figure bellow) should be over the tripping curve, like the green dashed curve in the figure above.

[image: Load limit curve for PVC-insulated cables - ABB - Comparison of tripping characteristics for miniature circuit-breakers]

Although this is enough to avoid nuisance tripping and ensure wire protection, it is not shown how motor protection is achieved.

**1. Is there any kind of “motor current/load limit curve”, like the one for wires? Is motor protection somehow always achieved because the IEC motors and IEC motor protective circuit breakers are both designed (according to IEC standards) in such a way that the "motor current limit curve" is always above cb’s tripping curve for a specific rated current?**

---

In the following figure from an [ABB document](https://library.e.abb.com/public/d1fabc89512548f09d3c09f1947115ae/1SBC100225M0201_Application%20Note%20-%20Motor%20starting%20and%20protection%20for%20NEMA%20Premium%20Efficiency.pdf), a high efficiency (IE2) motor is compared to a premium efficiency (IE3) motor. Because the latter has a higher starting current, it is very likely that nuisance tripping will happen (when using a motor starter for IE2).

[image: Diagram showing possibilities for an unexpected tripping - ABB - Motor starting and protection for premium efficiency motors]

The IEC Design Letter (N, H) have different locked rotor current, and starting requirements (according to [this](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-10/chapter-II/subchapter-D/part-431/subpart-B)). So, it seems that motor design N and design H have different starting current-time characteristics (assuming the same rated current), in a similar way to how IE2 vs IE3 motors have. Therefore, the IEC design letter (N or H) seems to matter for the selection of the motor starter.

**2.    So why isn’t the IEC Design Letter (N, H) taken in consideration when selecting a motor starter? Is it usually assumed that the motor is of type N?**

**3.    Is there a difference between N-type and H-type in the “motor current/load limit curve” (if such exists) in the same way that a 1.5mm^2 PVC wire has a different load limit curve from a 2.5mm^2 one?**

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Andyaka Not at all. I am trying to understand how a motor protective device is chosen from just its kw ratings, even though its time-current characteristics may differ between motors.

Comment: Looks like homework question wording!

Comment: Ok, I will try to rephrase it asap. I just tried to make it as easy to read and answer as possible. Ty for your feedback!

Comment: You have to show us some effort.  As in what do the parameters mean relative to starters.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, I edited the question so that it doesn't look like homework one, or at least I tried.

Comment: _"So, it seems that motor design N and design H have **different** starting current-time characteristics"_ - but is the difference significant? Show us examples.